# how to inset a new array to my jagged array

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

hello i will much apreciate any help.

ok let's see, first i have declare a jagged array like this and the next code

```
int n=1, m=3,p=0;

int[][] jag_array =new[n];
```

now my jagged array will have 1 array inside, next y have to fill the array like this:

```
car=2;
do
     {
     jag_array[p]= new double[car];
     for (int t = 0; t < carac; t++)
          {
           jag_array[p][t] = variableX;
          }
     p=p+1
     }
 while(p==0)
```

now my jagged array looks like this(also insert some data for this example):

```
jag_array[0][0]=4
jag_array[0][1]=2
```

now my question how can i insert a new array whit out losing my previos data if i declare

```
jag_array[p+1]= new double[car];
```

i will lose the data from the previos one, i will like to look something likes this:

```
jag_array[0][0]=4
jag_array[0][1]=2
jag_array[1][0]=5
jag_array[1][1]=6
```

the reason i did not declare from the begining 2 array is beacuse i dont know how many i am going to use it could be just 1 or 20 and every time i have to create a new array whit out losing the previous data that has been already fill, thaks all for the attention,

Comment: Any reason you can't use `List<int[]>`?

Comment: @recursive list wont work for the purpe of my program this the reason

Answer (score 2):

The size of an array, once created, is by definition invariable. If you need a variable number of elements, use a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) - in your case, probably a `List<int[]>`.

The only alternative solution would be to created a new array with the new size (and assign that to your `jag_array` variable) and copy all the previous elements from your old array into the new array. That is unnecessarily complicated code when you can just use `List<T>`, but if you cannot use `List<T>` for any reason, here is an example:

```
// increase the length of jag_array by one
var old_jag_array = jag_array; // store a reference to the smaller array
jag_array = new int[old_jag_array.Length + 1][]; // create the new, larger array
for (int i = 0; i < old_jag_array.Length; i++) {
    jag_array[i] = old_jag_array[i]; // copy the existing elements into the new array
}
jag_array[jag_array.Length - 1] = ... // insert new value here
```

Comment: @Daniel: What do you mean by that? In C#, arrays are a reference type, so an array of arrays is already, so-to-speak, an array of pointers to arrays.

Comment: Yeah, I thought this was a c++ question at first. Not that I would really recommend that in c++ either.

Comment: Is that true, though? Is `int[][]` an "array of arrays" in c# rather than a 2-d array? Those are different things with very different properties.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, that's true. In C#, a 2-d array would be written as `int[,]`, while `int[][]` is an array of arrays.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper for the porpuse of my program list are out of the equation :D i first use int[,] how ever i get to a complication, so have to change to jagedarray your anwser is good but not what a im looking for

Comment: @JUAN: From what you have told us so far, it does not get apparent why `List<T>` should not work, so obviously there is not enough information to tell what you *are* looking for. Please extend your question to make that clearer :-)

Comment: let me see first this example is a simple way to explain my problem, 2.- List are not part of my solution, it maybe more easy to use them but my program are not supose to used them one of the limitation for the proyect i am working, i cant enter to details of why i can only say that list are out :(

Comment: @JUAN: All right, assuming that `List<T>` is excluded for some reason, I've added a code sample that shows how to "append an element" to an array. I have written that in quotation marks because of course you don't really *append* anything to the existing array instance, you just replace the whole array instance with a new larger one. Therefore, you must make sure that you don't keep any other references to the old array but always use the `jag_array` variable to access the current array. (This is more or less what `List<T>` does internally, BTW.)