# C# increase length of a string array

Tags: c#, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to inset a new array to my jagged array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767023/how-to-inset-a-new-array-to-my-jagged-array)

i have a problem, where i dont know how i can make a string array variable in array length.

i have this code now below:

```
string[] p = new string[10];
int num = 0;

foreach (Product products in GetAllProducts())
    {
     //do something
     p[num]= "some variable result"
     num++
    }
```

The problem is, that i dont know how many of "p" i will get, although i know it atleast will be less than 10.
but if i put it on 0, i will get an error when i start it, because it doesn't know the "p[num]"
So i am looking for some way to make "p" have a variable length.

anyone could help me out a bit? thanx

============Solved==========

```
List<string> p = new List<string>();
int num = 0;

foreach (Product products in GetAllProducts())
    {
     string s= null;
     //do something ( create s out of multiple parts += s etc.)
     p.add(s)
     num++
    }
```

thanx to solution poster

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an [`List<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead of an array, if you do not know the number of items you will need to add.

Comment: Ahaa list. Didn't really know that one yet (i know i know, i aint no pro)  thanks for this one!

Answer (score 1):

Your array length cannot be modified after it has been instantiated. Use [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) or [Generic Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = new new List<string>(10);
foreach (Product products in GetAllProducts()) 
{ 
    //do something 
    p.Add("some variable result"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `GetAllProducts()` return? Does it have a count or a length?! You should call that first, save it in a variable, get the count/length and then declare your array!

Answer (score 0):

There's two solution.

If you want to keep using array :

```
int num = 0;
var list = GetAllProducts();
string[] p = new string[list.Length]; // Or list.Count if this is a collection

foreach (Product products in list)
{
    //do something
    p[num] = "some variable result";
    num++;
}
```

Otherwise you should use a List like this :

```
List<string> p = new List<string>();

foreach (Product products in GetAllProducts())
{
    //do something
    p.Add("some variable result");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.Resize() method, which allows to resize it (by n number of indexes).
In my exmaple I will reize by 1 on each step of the way:

```
        string[] array = new string[3]; //create array
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (array.Length-1 < i) //checking for the available length
            {
                Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length + 1); //when to small, create a new index
            }
            array[i] = i.ToString(); //add an item to array[index] - of i
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your code is using a foreach on the result from GetAllProducts, then GetAllProducts must be returning a [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) collection. Probably the best solution would be to simply assign the result of GetAllProducts to such a collection. For example, perhaps it already returns a list of strings? So you can do:

```
List<string> strings = GetAllProducts();
```

There is no need to have a foreach loop to create an array when you already have a collection anyway being returned from GetAllProducts.

Or simply:

```
var strings = GetAllProducts();
```

to let the compiler work out the type of strings.

Most things you can do with an array you can also do with a List, and some more (such as adding items to the end of the List).

Perhaps you can post the signature of GetAllProducts (especially its return type) so we can better advise you?

Answer (score 0):

I see many gave you the right answer which is the use of Lists. If you still need an array in the end, you can easily convert your list into an Array like this :

```
    string[] tempArray = myList.ToArray();
```